# Unable to enable replication

Tags: replication, opendj

I want to configure a multi-master replication between two instances of Opendj on two different machine: the first is on localhost, the second is on virtualbox.
I have Opendj installed on both machines. I can't enable replication because I don't know how to connecto to the virtual station. The command:

```
./bin/dsreplication enable --host1 work_station --port1 4444 --bindDN1 \
"cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword1 password --replicationPort1 8989 \ 
--host2 virtual_station --port2 4444 --bindDN2 "cn=Directory Manager" \
--bindPassword2 password --replicationPort2 8989 --adminUID admin \
--adminPassword password --baseDN "dc=example,dc=com" -X -n
```

gives me the output:

```
Establishing connections ..... 
Could not connect to virtual_station:4444. Check that the server is running and
that it is accessible from the local machine.  Details: virtual_station:4444
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to enable replication between 2 machines (physical or virtual), the OpenDJ service must be able to resolve both names (either from DNS or local hosts file) and to connect to the different machines and ports.
Make sure both names can be resolved from each machine, and also make sure that you do not have a firewall or other configuration that are blocking ports.